# CoreData Or Segue For Accessing Class Instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have an app that requires the same data in multiple view controllers. Currently to access this data I use performSegue to send the class instance from one controller to another as I navigate the app.

**My question is this:** Is it cleaner code to instead use CoreData to access the data within each view controller? Instead of using the performSegue I could query the coreData at ViewDidLoad and then convert the string I retrieve from CoreData to a the class instance object.

Comment: I would pass the NSManagedObject instance through `prepareForSegue`. That way you don't have to worry about re-fetching data as you navigate back through the view stack

Comment: Thanks Paul! That's what I will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a managed object along as you describe is one approach to the dependency injection software design pattern, and is generally a better idea than having each view controller look up the object(s) it needs.

Will these view controllers ever **need** to look up a managed object on their own? That is, would they ever be used when it wouldn't be possible to pass in a managed object or where it's not possible to pass in the right one for some reason? If so then it might make sense for them to be able to look up managed objects. If not, then doing so will lead to duplicate code and increased complexity with no benefit.

In short it sounds like you're already doing the right thing, and that you shouldn't make the change you describe unless you know of a compelling reason for it.

Comment: Thanks Tom. That does seem to be the best option. I think I just got a little too excited about the idea of using CoreData for everything.